# display RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-5.0-lollipop

I want to ask how to apply recyclerview in fragment

I'm using BottomNavigationView with Fragment and I want to install the recyclerview in the first fragment, I'm so confused because it's so hard, I try it many times but it's always an error

I hope you guys can help me

its my ItemOneFragment

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_one, container, false);


    List<ItemObject> rowListItem = getAllItemList();
    lLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);

    RecyclerView rView = (RecyclerView)v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    rView.setLayoutManager(lLayout);

    RecyclerViewAdapter rcAdapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(MainActivity.this, rowListItem);
    rView.setAdapter(rcAdapter);

    return v;
}
private List<ItemObject> getAllItemList(){

    List<ItemObject> allItems = new ArrayList<ItemObject>();
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United States", R.drawable.newyork));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Canada", R.drawable.canada));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("United Kingdom", R.drawable.uk));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Germany", R.drawable.germany));
    allItems.add(new ItemObject("Sweden", R.drawable.sweden));

    return allItems;
}
}
```

Comment: What output you are getting and what is the expected output? Are you getting any exception or error or no UI?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?